# Datagrid bottom border visible though BorderThickness="0"

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a problem that the border bottom on my datagrid is still visible even though I have set `BorderThickness="0"` The following code is my datagrid markup:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductInformations}" IsReadOnly="True" 
    HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
    BorderThickness="0" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
 </DataGrid>
```

On the image there is a barely visible line "under the datagrid"

[image]
Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out by changing the datagrid `Background="White"` Looks like the default background color for the datagrid was showing a bit at the bottom of the grid.